# Is it possible to detect infection in PSP Go game console?

Tags: malware

My PSP is acting like it could possibly be infected.  It is locking up and then turns off during game play.  There are also problems during games that could be related.  This is a replacement PSP machine because I thought my old one was defective but now this one is doing the same thing.  Someone in customer service 
claimed it couldn't be infected but now I have my doubts.

I am using the same memory stick and some of the same data that was stored on the old console.  I've never visited any suspicious web sites or installed any software that wasn't either pre-installed or from the Playstation store. I also downloaded the Music Unlimited service from the Sony website. I have only updated the firmware using the update function on the console.  I've suspected for years that my computer may be infected by something undetected and I used the same WI-FI network with both consoles. I had also connected the original PSP Go to the computer with a USB cable to transfer digital copies of movies.

Comment: I've never heard about getting viruses on PSP consoles of any variety. I'm not sure why you'd bother to make one other than as a PoC but you need to explain what you've done to the console that seems like an infection point. Did you install a custom firmware? Do you use it to do anything other than play bought games? What did you do to the old one that has happened to this new one as well?

Comment: This is by far more likely just a case of bad memory stick and due to bad cells the file system is failing. I wouldn't know for PSP Go, but most CE devices only do a quick format of memory cards (which would complete in seconds, not minutes) and don't check the integrity of the media. If you have a tool to do a complete format on your PSP Go, then use that one. It will take longer to complete, but will also make sure all the allocated sectors can be written to. Not sure why you'd think it's a virus, though. Even if it was, it has absolutely nothing to gain from locking/freezing the device up.

Comment: Also, check suggestion on [this page](http://www.ehow.com/info_12206953_pspgo-freezes.html).

Comment: If you suspected your computer is infected why have you not cleaned the infection?  Your PSP does not have an infection.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the RAM and look for possible rogue code. I'm sure you won't find anything though, your device is probably just broken.

Answer (score 1):

You could monitor the network traffic in and out using Wireshark (or similar), and check whether there is anything unexpected.